# How do I join these or union these

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

client

- idclient
- name
- reference

address

- idaddress
- idclient

inv

- idinvoice
- idaddress
- datetime
- total

payment

- idpayment
- idinvoice
- pdatetime
- amount

**into** - name, reference, time, idpayment, idinvoice, amount

i.e. datetime and pdatetime as time. inv.total as negative amount. Where idaddress = 9

Comment: please make clear your question and text.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm making quite a few assumptions about what you're asking, but it looks like you are going for this:

```
select
    c.name
    , c.reference
    , c.pdatetime as time
    , p.idpayment
    , i.idinvoice
    , p.amount
from
    payment p
    inner join inv i
        on p.idinvoice = i.idinvoice
    inner join address a
        on i.idaddress = a.idaddress
    inner join client c
        on a.idclient = c.idclient
```

add whatever filtering you need in a where clause

Comment: what about inv.total

inv.total as negative amount

If there are 3 invoice and 3 payments, I would expect 6 rows. 3 rows of column idpayment would be NULL and 3 rows of idinvoice would be NULL too.